# unable to get the results from the yahoo finance api for my site due cross domain funcationality

Tags: jquery, ajax

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quote.csve=.csv&s=^BSESN&f=nl1c2vgh&random=10",true);

    xmlhttp.send(null);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {

         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
         {
    window.alert(xmlhttp.status);
    }
            }

**The above code showing status 200 in IE But in Firefox and Chrome got the status 0 due cross domain functionality.
Can any one help to how to overcome this cross domain functionality using java script.**

Comment: Nope, but you could do it on the serverside?

Comment: can use Yahoo YQL to access it. It is a cross domain proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct call to other domain is not possible from JavaScript ajax due to cross domain issue best way to do this type of call is call your own webpage using Ajax and from your server side script call these apis and get answer and return to your ajax call.

if you are using php you can use **cURL** OR **file_get_contents** to fetch content from url

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for your information. If I call any php script then request goes to the my sever ip.  I think there is limit to access data from yahoo from single IP. So, I need to call to the yahoo api from client side. Is there any way to overcome cross domain either using any of the Dojo or any other script libraries?

Comment: its not the problem of javascript, modern browsers not allowed to do this for security issue. and accessing from server is always a good way as you don't need to pass your secret info on the client side.